# Auto generate serial no in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate serial no in gridview asp.net.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this

```
     <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
             <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note : DataItemIndex - Gets the index of the DataItem in the underlying DataSet.

Answer (score 4):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCart" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="table_04" HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="table_02" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>' CssClass="form-label"></asp:Label>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10px"></ItemStyle>
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
```